Set Client_id when createToken (Laravel Passport)
is there a way to customize client_id when using createToken? my code: $user = User::find(1); $token = $user->createToken('xx',[],['client_id' => 2]);
Expected results: client_id in table oauth_access_tokensclient_id in the oauth_access_to table (client_id = 2)
Actual results: client_id = 13 new when run passport:install
